# Extracting HTML information from a URL

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program in python that reads all the data from a web page and appends the contents of any of the heading tags `<h1>` through `<h6>` to a list. So far I'm just trying to get the website information in the first place, which has proven to be difficult.

Edit: This is for a class. Sadly, we aren't allowed to use libraries that don't come pre-installed with python.

Edit 2: Thank you for all your tips. The program now successfully reads the HTML of a given website. Does anybody have any suggestions to search for a specific string (being the `<H>` tags) within webPage?

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

#example URL that includes an <h> tag: http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/
userAddress = input("Enter a website URL: ")

webPage = urllib.request.urlopen(userAddress)

print (webPage.read())

webPage.close()
```

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ and http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using `python3` for fetching the web page.
It can be fetched by following code:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

address = "http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/"
webPage = urllib.request.urlopen(address)

print (webPage.read())
```

For pulling out information from a webpage, you can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
It is an incredible tool for pulling out information from a webpage. You can use it to extract tables, lists, paragraph and you can also put filters to extract information from web pages.

Install it from here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `requests` library.

```
import requests 

r = requests.get('http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/')
print(r.text)
```

check the docs out at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the beautifulsoup library. Its an API for parsing the DOM tree.
You can do things like soup.find_all('h1') which will return a list of all h1 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `with open` so it automatically closes connections. Heres an example:

```
import urllib.request
address = "http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/"
with urllib.request.urlopen(address) as response:
   html = response.read()
   print html
```

Answer (score 0):

your `webPage` variable is a network object, to actually get the html content use

```
content = webPage.read()
```

for getting the contents of the heading tag you can use the `BeautifulSoup` library

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlContent = webPage.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, from_encoding=htmlContent.info().getparam('charset'))
heads = soup.find_all('head').text
```

now `heads` is a list of the content of all occurrences of the head tag

to read more about the `BeautifulSoup` library go to: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/